# Audio streaming from python server to js client

Tags: javascript, python, audio-streaming, chunked

I wanted to write an app that would stream audio from python server to js client.
I want the audio to be streamed in chunks so the user doesn't have to wait for the audio when on a slow connection. I never really worked with either audio or streaming in python and js so I have no idea what I'm doing but if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be very appreciated.

Comment: You can simply respond with an MP3/OGG/... stream from your HTTP endpoint. The details on how to return a streaming response depend on the HTTP framework you'd be using on your server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.